# Get Nodejs Promise value for use in existing Framework object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js

Amateur JavaScript guy here. I've written a private NodeJS module that manages our DB connection strings (Decrypt passwords & connection string construction), but due to the nature of the decrypt, the module returns a promise for the db connection string.

We are using Sails, and the config happens in the export of a variables object:

```
module.exports.variables = { dbstring: 'mongodb://user:password@host/mydb' }
```

But now with the promise, it's a little trickier to squeeze a string in here. I've tried putting the 'module.exports.variables' block, inside a '.then' block:

```
myConfigModule.getDBString('mysql-master').then( result => {
  module.exports.variables = { dbstring: result }
}
```

but then the rest of the sails app fails to start up, with it trying to access variables inside 'module.exports.variables', and only gets 'undefined'. I assume because the rest of the app isn't waiting for the promise to be fulfilled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share getDBString function? module.exports does not wait for `getDBString` promise to resolve. In this case, a file is already exported before resolving the promise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd export a function from your module getDBString, e.g.

**Config Module (config.js)**

```
var getDBString = function() {
    /* Query DB, returning a promise. */
    return queryDB('mysql-master');
}

module.exports = {
    getDBString: getDBString
};
```

**Main Module**

```
var config = require('/config.js');
config.getDBString().then((dbString) => {
    console.log('DB string: ', dbString)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this, but it's mostly sails.js specific. The sails.lift() method allows you to pass override configs, so in the app.js, I was then able to use my promise to pass the db configs to sails app:

```
myConfigModule.getDBString('mysql-master').then( result => {
  const sailsOverrideSettings.connections = {
    someMySQLServer: {
      url: result
    }
  };
  sails.lift(sailsOverrideSettings);
})
.catch ( err => {
  // Throw error up the stack.
  throw (err)
});
```

Reference:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-lift